# youtube API - setShuffle don't work

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, playlist

I added this script in my site to reproduce video playlist.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>  
<div id="ytapiplayer">
You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var params = { allowScriptAccess: 'always',
allowFullScreen: 'true' };
var atts = { id: 'myytplayer' };
swfobject.embedSWF("https://www.youtube.com/v/videoseries?listType=playlist&list=PLBA9E733B5C8314DE&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3", "ytapiplayer", "640", "360", "8", null, null, params, atts);
function onYouTubePlayerReady(myytplayer) {
        ytSwfPlayer = document.getElementById( 'myytplayer' );
        ytSwfPlayer.setShuffle(1);
}
</script>
```

the setShuffle function don't work!!! 
You can suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the player.  I've reported this bug to the team.  In the future you can report bugs at [https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report)](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Defect%20Report%29)

As a work around you could use the JS api to shuffle it yourself.  When a video ends you can call `playVideoAt` and pass a random number.

Comment: I am experiencing the same error and while I implemented the random number solution, it is not optimal as it can repeat a video by selecting the same random number.  I'm also having inconsistent results with the playVideoAt function.  Is anyone aware of a more robust solution or have knowledge of when the bug will be fixed?

Comment: the bug seems to be fixed now.
note: every time you set a new video or playlist, you need to call setShuffle() again.  I think same goes for some other settings, like setLoop()

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you've loaded a playlist queue in the Youtube player, the next track will automatically start at the end of the current playing one.

So you should bind track ended event (which is `event.data = 0`) and then make the youtube player make two things:

1. stop playing
2. play a new track with a random index by calling `playVideoAt` method.

A simple solution to avoid repeating the same track more times is to store the played idx in a list. Then, you should have a function, like `shuffle` that generates a random integer between 0 and the queue length:

```
function getRandomId() {
    var random_id = 0
    while(played_idx.indexOf(random_id) != -1) {
      random_id = Math.floor(Math.random * playlist.length)
    }
    return random_id
}
```

Then, simply call `playVideoAt(random_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that setShuffle does work if you launch the command a little later. Something like this:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.mute();
    setTimeout( function() { 
        event.target.setShuffle(true); 
        event.target.setLoop(true);
    }, 2000);
}
```

If you launch it directly, it will definitely not work (I have noticed, to my frustration).