# Still Possible to set Shuffle Settings on Iframe Embed Code?

Tags: iframe, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am deciding whether or not I should use the full YouTube API (registering for an API key, calling the YouTube JS and building the player from scratch) or if I should just register for an YouTube account, build a playlist and load this playlist on a client's website as is (using the iframe embed code, seen below):

```
  <iframe width="100%" height="315" 
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=XXXXXXX
  &autoplay=1&rel=0&loop=1&shuffle=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
```

The embed code is easy enough, but from viewing earlier videos on YouTube Playlist settings, YouTube has removed quite a bit of functionality from basic playlist settings (autoplay, shuffling videos on play, start/stop times of each video in playlist, etc.)

I would imagine the switch for shuffle should be as easy as "&shuffle=1" or something like that. I'm not sure why YouTube makes it so difficult to comprehend new settings after having removed such a powerful feature from such a simple embed code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an *actual* solution:

```
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    setTimeout(setShuffleFunction, 1000);           
  }
  function setShuffleFunction(){
    player.setShuffle(true);
  }
```

You have to use javascript to load the player.setShuffle(true) event, just after the first video starts (solution given here: [YouTube API playlist shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866979/youtube-api-playlist-shuffle-not-working/34881913)). I didn't create it but I tried it and it worked for me too. I went two years thinking the feature was deprecated and no longer possible with embedded playlists. Seeing as this is the primary response when you google this issue, figured I'd help out.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the embed parameters YouTube supports [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I should probably mention that I have marked this as the answer, as the shuffle option is not there and therefore currently not available for iFrame API. I must use the pure API and code the shuffle settings from there. NOTE: The YouTube iFrame settings have been decreased as of 2016.