# YouTube API When video is done

Tags: javascript, events, youtube-api

I am using YouTube API and I am trying to set-up an onStateChange when my video ends to shuffle my playlist and start at 0...this is what I got thus far

```
 var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }

        });
      }





      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        player.loadPlaylist({'listType': 'playlist', 'list': 'PLF776D41D8211F340','index': '0','startSeconds': '0','suggestedQuality': 'hd720'});
      }

      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && done == false) {
            player.setShuffle(true);
            player.playVideoAt(0);
          done = true;
        }else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED && done == true) {
            player.setShuffle(true);
            player.playVideoAt(0);
          done = false;
        }

      }
```

What Am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `player.playVideoAt(0)` within the `onPlayerReady` function.

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.loadPlaylist({'listType': 'playlist', 'list': 'PLF776D41D8211F340','index': '0','startSeconds': '0','suggestedQuality': 'hd720'});
    player.playVideo();
  }
```

Also as you are playing the first video from the playlist, why not use `player.playVideo()` instead.

I didn't include the `player.setShuffle(true)` because it currently is not working (known bug) - see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916017/youtube-api-setshuffle-dont-work).